# I want to crawl SSIS ETL packages stored on disk

Tags: python, ssis, scrapy

Can Python read the .dtsx file? It is the file extension of Microsoft SSIS ETL packages. I want to write a Python program that will crawl SSIS packages and scrape all the table names. Thanks

Comment: I would start by looking at a python XML parser. https://lxml.de/ would be a good start. Otherwise you can complete simple queries in T-SQL..

Comment: Thanks Red. For start, I have started with xml.etree.ElementTree.

Answer (score 1):

SSIS packages are really just big XML documents. For most purposes, you can treat them like any other text doc. I routinely use the "Find In Files" option in Notepad++ to do just the sort of thing you're looking to do programmatically.

Be careful, of course, because accidental edits can hopelessly break the packages. (Nothing that I have *any* experience with. Really. I swear.)

Comment: Thanks Eric. Now, I see that Python is not bothered about the SSIS extension .dtsx. It is treating the file as XML, I guess that is because the content is XML. xml.etree.ElementTree is parsing it perfectly.